# Android Studio change color of the app name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

fHow can I change the color of the app name, I have changed the toolbar text color to white but the app name is still in black. I have also noticed if I change the color of the bar to black the app name color becomes white. I want the app name color to be like WhatsApp.

[image]

Comment: It depends on the shell of the view. On my Honor 8x, all application names are white on a transparent background

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

I hope it will help you .

Answer (score 0):

You can try Custom Toolbar with Custom Color Values..
[image: Create Custom Style Theme for Toolbar in Style.xml]

[image: In this You can use your Toolbar theme in Custom Toolbar]